# Odftoolkit Paste document with TextUserFieldDeclElement

Tags: java, reporting-services, field, odt, odftoolkit

I'm using the Odtftoolkit library in Java, and I have a process that uses a template document with `TextUserFieldDeclElement`. My process makes two diferents documents from the same template, and I need to show both pages in the same document. My problem is that `TextUserFieldDeclElement` of the first page shows the same value that the second page.

My code is like this:

1: Make each document (I call to this metodos first with a object "plantilla", and after, with other diferent object "plantilla").

```
TextDocument outputOdt = TextDocument.loadDocument(new File(plantilla));

OdfElement contenedor = outputOdt.getVariableContainerElement();

org.w3c.dom.NodeList nodos = contenedor
        .getElementsByTagName("text:user-field-decl");

for (int i = 0; i < nodos.getLength(); i++) {

    if (nodos.item(i) instanceof TextUserFieldDeclElement) {

        TextUserFieldDeclElement txt = (TextUserFieldDeclElement) nodos
                .item(i);

        if (txt.getTextNameAttribute() != null) {

            // Consultamos si el atributo está en el hash
            if (poGlobal.containsKey(txt.getTextNameAttribute())) {
                outputOdt.getVariableFieldByName(
                        txt.getTextNameAttribute()).updateField(
                        poGlobal.get(txt.getTextNameAttribute()),
                        null);
            }

        }
    }
}

File ficTmp = Fichero.dameFicheroTemporal(".odt");

// Volcamos al fichero temporal
outputOdt.save(ficTmp);

arDocumentos.add(ficTmp);
```

2: I work with the arDocuments Array and try to copy all documents into the same as:

```
try {

    TextDocument target = TextDocument.loadDocument(this.arDocumentos
            .get(0));

    // Por cada documento, copiamos y pegamos en el destino
    for (int i = 1; i < this.arDocumentos.size(); i++) {
        Paragraph parrafo = target.addParagraph(null);
        TextDocument src = TextDocument.loadDocument(this.arDocumentos
                .get(i));

        target.insertContentFromDocumentAfter(src, parrafo, false);

    }

    target.save(new File(destino));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new CtrError("Error al cerrar el documento.", ex);
}
```